# Why jQuery.parseJSON affect to the method load?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load a part of the page after ajax... So I am using this code in java script after based on the data returned:

```
var getPrice = $(this).closest('li');
var price = getPrice.next();
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.ajaxSetup({
        url: "do_cart_actions.php?action=qty",
        type: 'POST', 
        data: data, 
        success: function(data) {

            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            if(result.good == 1) {
                price.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    price.load('show_cart.php .item_price_'+id, function() {
                        price.fadeIn('fast');
                    });
                });
            }
        }
   });
   $.ajax();
```

My php file return this:

```
echo '{ "good":"1" , "qty":"'. $_POST['a'] .'" }';
```

When I try this, chrome return the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The weird thing is that the code work with the `fadeOut` and if I remove the `.load` also work with the `fadeIn`.... either if I delete the `var result` and return an number '2' from my php file and modifying my javascript like this:

```
if(data == 2) {
        price.fadeOut('fast', function() {
            price.load('show_cart.php .item_price_'+id, function() {
                price.fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });
}
```

Now, everything work well again. So my only theory is that maybe there is a problem with the load method and jQuery.parseJSON

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server side:

```
echo json_encode(array('good'=>1,'qty'=>$_POST['a']));
```

Clienti side: use **dataType**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            url: "do_cart_actions.php?action=qty",
            type: 'POST', 
            data: data, 
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(result) {

            if(result.good == 1) {
                price.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    price.load('show_cart.php .item_price_'+id, function() {
                        price.fadeIn('fast');
                    });
                });
            }
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 4):

1st at your PHP..
Instead

```
echo '{ "good":"1" , "qty":"'. $_POST['a'] .'" }';
```

you have very easy to use json function as:

```
echo json_encode(array('good'=>1,'qty'=>$_POST['a']));
```

2nd at your javascript at:

```
success: function(data) {
    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

you don't need to parse data because its already in JSON format.

To be sure about that before echo json_encode at you PHP code you can add and json headers as:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

!!! P.S. !!!

DO NOT USE ajaxSetup to process your request! It will effect any next ajax  request you made and this can be a problem later!

Comment: only one question how retrieve the info from in javascript then?

Comment: success: function(data) data is your result

Comment: yes but I mean how to do something like: if(data[good] == 1) { alert('going well') }

Comment: You need to learn javascript syntax.. instead of data[good] use data.good

Comment: yes I have tried but based in another question I was missing the datatype 'json' :)

Comment: Datatype to json is good but not without the proper answer from your PHP. 
Usually with setting json headers at your php response your jquery should recognize that its a JSON format automatic. Btw DO NOT use ajaxSetup for such things as it will has effect on all other ajax requests..

Comment: thanks for all your help, I have used the header and have change the ajax setup... and vote also haha

Answer (score 1):

What is it?

```
price.load('show_cart.php .item_price_'+id, // ...
```

Why do you combine the path to PHP file and CSS selector?

I may guess that it tries to load the given URL like `show_cart.php .item_price_3`, finds no such page (obviously), returns HTML page with 404 error, which is not being parsed to JSON because of tag opening `<`. Open your developers console, `Network` tab and you will see that you are making a wrong request with an inadequate URL.

Also, why do you use `$.ajaxSetup`? For a particular AJAX call, you should use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "do_cart_actions.php?action=qty",
    type: 'POST', 
    data: data, 
    success: function(data) {
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        if(result.good == 1) {
            price.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                price.load('show_cart.php .item_price_'+id, function() {
                    price.fadeIn('fast');
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

});

Also, note, that `success` is deprecated in the latest jQuery versions. Use `.done()` handler instead.

Comment: you mean `.success()`

Comment: @madalinivascu No, I mean `done()`. The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8

Comment: you are referring to `success` as `$.ajax({}).success()` not as `$.ajax({success:function(){}})`

Comment: I am trying to update a price if the customer change the quantity... so I pass the id from the quantity input to the price tag to update only that price... sorry I am trying to explain in the best way I can

Comment: that way to use ajax combined with the other question make it work!!! Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to show in a console.log() ?

the content of **result** after

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Just in case something is wrong in it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, this should be an comment asking for additional information.

Comment: hey to do this I should add this 'console.log(result);' isnt?

Comment: @KhorneHoly I'm not be able to post comments because I don't have at least 50 reputation, this is why I've posted as an answer. I think it is not a reason to give thumbs down to my answer. I'm just only trying to help...

Comment: That's it @TomasLucena try to show the result in a console.log just after the var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data); :)

Comment: only return this Object {good: 1, qty: "18"}
myCart:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the content of your PHP file??

Comment: hey dude, fixed, it has worked with the answer below